# python requests library response format

Tags: python, http, python-requests

I've recently starting using the requests library (which is excellent).  However when I get a request response via a post method it seems to return a String(unicode) , when I check the type, even though it looks like a dictionary - which makes it more difficult to pull data from it.

Is there a way to have the json data returned in dictionary format, so I can easily extract a couple of fields?

specifically a request like:

```
>>> payload = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}
>>> r = requests.post("http://httpbin.org/post", data=payload)
>>> print(r.text)
{
  ...
  "form": {
    "key2": "value2",
    "key1": "value1"
  },
  ...
}
```

r.text is a unicode string not a dictionary (even though it looks like one above)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `json` method of response object.

```
print r.json()
```

Comment: And after that the OP could use this post to interpret the json object as a dictionary http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19483351/converting-json-string-to-dictionary-not-list-python

You could verify it and add it to your answer if you want.

Answer (score 1):

Use Requests built-in json decoder:

```
r.json()
```

see: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content

Comment: This link is unfortunately broken now. In following link is active documentation: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content