# Python list through text file and removing lines that match a duplicated value

Tags: python

I'm currently iterating  through a text file and getting back the following output, to make my script effective I would like to delete the duplicate
strings containing e.g. 181 and just keep one, see the example below.

**Log file to be parsed.**

```
{"id": "242", "status": 61313850, "time": "2015-02-26T08:46:14.070298", "item": 181, }
{"id": "242", "status": 61313850, "time": "2015-02-26T08:46:14.070298", "item": 181, }
{"id": "242", "status": 61313850, "time": "2015-02-26T08:46:14.070298", "item": 181, }
{"id": "242", "status": 61313850, "time": "2015-02-26T08:46:14.070298", "item": 181, }
{"id": "242", "status": 61313850, "time": "2015-02-26T08:46:14.070298", "item": 181, }
{"id": "242", "status": 61313851, "time": "2015-02-26T08:46:14.070298", "item": 180, }
```

**Python code.**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

with open("tras.json") as infile:
    for line in infile:

    if "time" in line:
        time=line.split()[4:6]

    if "item" in line:
        item=line.split()[6:8]
        print time + item
```

**Current output.**

```
['"time":', '"2015-02-26T08:46:14.070298",', '"item":', '181,']
['"time":', '"2015-02-26T08:46:14.070298",', '"item":', '181,']
['"time":', '"2015-02-26T08:46:14.070298",', '"item":', '181,']
['"time":', '"2015-02-26T08:46:14.070298",', '"item":', '181,']
['"time":', '"2015-02-26T08:46:14.070298",', '"item":', '181,']
['"time":', '"2015-02-26T08:46:14.070298",', '"item":', '180,']
```

**Desired output.**

```
['"time":', '"2015-02-26T08:46:14.070298",', '"item":', '181,']
['"time":', '"2015-02-26T08:46:14.070298",', '"item":', '180,']
```

Cheers,

Phillip

Comment: Your forgot to include the Python code you use to solve this problem. You also forgot to describe what problem you have with this code.

Comment: Sorry for that, I've just added the code used to iterate. Phillip

Comment: 1) This Python code will not produce this output. 2) What does not work with your code?

Comment: My code produce exactly what I've posted above.

Comment: `print time + item` will not produce output  like `['"time":', '"2015-02-26T08:46:14.070298", '"item":', '181,']`.

Comment: The if statements probably need to be indented.  I'm guessing this is a typo in your question.  This might be instructive: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19483351/converting-json-string-to-dictionary-not-list-python

Answer (score 1):

A complete answer would require more knowledge of your domain, but I hope this example code is helpful:

```
foundNumbers=set()
clearedData=list()
for dataItem in dataList:
    if dataItem[-1] not in foundNumbers:
        foundNumbers.add(dataItem[-1])
        clearedData.append(dataItem)
```