# "TypeError: string indices must be integers not str" seting a var from a dictionary key

Tags: python, dictionary, typeerror

I grab info from an API call that comes in the form of a dictionary. I need to grab a specific key and set a variable to it. Easy enough but observe. The code below is only to the processes involved.

```
totalEntries = 0  # global var
api_data = requests.get(apiEndpoint).json()

def populateVars():
    global totalEntries
    totalEntries = api_data['total_entries']
```

output of the `api_data` just for giggles:

```
 {u'per_page': 100, u'total_entries': 1, u'current_page': 1, `u'restaurants': [{u'city': u'Abilene', u'reserve_url': u'http://www.opentable.com/single.aspx?rid=152869', u'name': u'Copper Creek Fine Texas Dining', u'area': u'Dallas - Fort Worth', u'country': u'US', u'price': 2, u'phone': u'3256924424', u'state': u'TX', u'postal_code': u'79602', u'address': u'4401 Loop 322', u'lat': 32.397913, u'image_url': u'https://www.opentable.com/img/restimages/152869.jpg', u'lng': -99.716776, u'mobile_reserve_url': u'http://mobile.opentable.com/opentable/?restId=152869', u'id': 152869}]}`
```

and again the error:

```
  totalEntries = api_data['total_entries']
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

Why is this happening? What is the fix?

Comment: `api_data` is clearly a string, and e.g. `'foo'['bar']` would make no sense at all.

Comment: Take a look at the json library https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

Comment: can you expand jonrsharpe please

Comment: jonrsharpe either offer useful advice on my problem or exit

Comment: @ChristopherJakob don't be so rude. I *have* offered some useful advice, and the error message is telling you exactly what the problem is. *"I grab info from an API call that comes in the form of a dictionary"* is clearly a false assumption.

Comment: @ChristopherJakob As jon has already said, `api_data` is a `str` type, you cannot index out of it. You have to [convert it to a valid `dict`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19483351/converting-json-string-to-dictionary-not-list-python)

Comment: @ChristopherJakob what did I just say? [Be nice](http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice); you're the one coming here demanding that strangers help you when you can't even be bothered to correctly type the error message into the title box. Shape up, or ship out.

Comment: so it turns out that my var api_data is a dictionary ( I just did a type method on it) it seems these methods you guys have given me which I must say thank you for, may not apply.

Comment: You wouldn't get that error message if `isinstance(api_data, dict)`; please provide a [mcve] that recreates the issue. You would probably find development and debugging easier with explicit parameters, rather than `global` variables.

Answer (score 2):

As jonsharpe already pointed out, your `api_data` is a string, which can only be indexed by integers.

Instead of using:

```
api_data = requests.get(apiEndpoint).json()
```

consider using [`json.load`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.load):

```
resp = requests.get(apiEndpoint)
api_data = json.loads(resp.text)
```