# Iterate over JSON objects in Python

Tags: python, json, firebase

I get JSON from firebase (simplified):

```
logitems = {
u'-K7w56QCnpYI': { u'Date': 1452707179865.0618, u'Message': 'messagetest1' },
u'-K7w56safnpYI': { u'Date': 1452707179867.0618, u'Message': 'messagetest2' },
u'-FSDFSDddsfsI': { u'Date': 1452707179868.0618, u'Message': 'messagetest3' },
}
```

How can I iterate over the items (stored with keys instead in an array)?

Comment: for v in `logitems.values()`? `.itervalues()` for Py2.

Comment: with 2700+ rep, you should be able to formulate a proper question, or at the very least be able to search SO or Google. Look here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to reference your items as shown in this post here.

[Converting JSON String to Dictionary Not List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19483351/converting-json-string-to-dictionary-not-list-python)

Then you can wrap your iteration in a for loop.

Comment: Thanks for selecting my answer I was convinced I would never get to comment on Stack Exchange :)

Answer (score 0):

Right answer is in comment from Rogalski:

```
for v in logitems.values()? .itervalues() for Py2
```