# How to efficiently decode a large number of small JSON data chunks?

Tags: python, json

I'm going to write a parser for a log file where each line is one JSON record.

I could decode each line in a loop:

```
logs = [json.loads(line) for line in lines]
```

or I could decode the whole file in one go:

```
logs = json.loads('[' + ','.join(lines) + ']')
```

I want to minimize the execution time, please disregard other factors. Is there any reason to prefer one approach over the other?

Comment: I think decoding the whole file in one go si faster because it avoid a potentially slow loop (but it is less pythonic), however you better should try yourself both solution and benchmark it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily test it with [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/timeit.html#timeit-command-line-interface):

```
$ python -m timeit -s 'import json; lines = ["{\"foo\":\"bar\"}"] * 1000' '[json.loads(line) for line in lines]'
100 loops, best of 3: 2.22 msec per loop
$ python -m timeit -s 'import json; lines = ["{\"foo\":\"bar\"}"] * 1000' "json.loads('[' + ','.join(lines) + ']')"
1000 loops, best of 3: 839 usec per loop
```

In this case combining the data and parsing it one go is about 2.5 times faster.

Answer (score 0):

You can just make the log as a JSON dictionary.
Like

```
{    
"log":{
     "line1":{...}
     "line2":{...}
    ...
    }
}
```

And then do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19483351/converting-json-string-to-dictionary-not-list-python) that explains how to convert and use JSON into dictionary in Python

So you can use it directly without parsing