# Python - convert JSON object to dict

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I am wondering how I can convert a json list to a dictionary using the two values of the JSON objects as the key/value pair. 
The JSON looks like this:

```
"test": [
                {
                    "name": "default",
                    "range": "100-1000"
                },
                {
                    "name": "bigger",
                    "range": "1000-10000"
                }
        ]
```

I basically want the dictionary to use the name as the key and the range as the value. SO the dictionary in this case would be `{default:100-1000} {bigger: 1000-10000}`

Is that possible?

Comment: You want to change a string to an integer..? Maybe you should start by setting your JSON strings to integers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting JSON String to Dictionary Not List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19483351/converting-json-string-to-dictionary-not-list)

Comment: But in your question, you define two dictionaries as output?

Comment: Keyword: [dict  comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1747817/416224).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can first load the JSON string into a dictionary with `json.loads`. Next you can use dictionary comprehension to post process it:

```
from json import loads

{ d['name'] : d['range'] for d in loads(json_string)['test'] }
```

We then obtain:

```
>>> { d['name'] : d['range'] for d in loads(json_string)['test'] }
{'bigger': '1000-10000', 'default': '100-1000'}
```

In case there are two sub-dictionaries with the same *name*, then the last one will be stored in the result.