# Convert nested PHP Array to nested Python Dictionary

Tags: php, python, arrays, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a PHP script and want to write that in Python. So,
How can I convert this nested PHP Array to nested python [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)?

```
$data = [
    'details'=> [
        [
          ['quick_event'=> 'Quick'], 
          ['advance_event'=> 'Advanced']
        ],
        [
          ['help'=> 'Help']
        ]
    ],
    'has_car'=> true,
    'has_payment'=> false
];
```

I created this in Python but it's wrong:

```
data = {
    'details': {
        {
          {'quick_event': 'Quick'}, 
          {'advance_event': 'Advanced'}
        },
        {
          {'help': 'Help'}
        }
    },
    'has_car': True,
    'has_payment': False
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question is rather narrow but here we go:

```
data = {
    'details': [
        [
          {'quick_event': 'Quick'}, 
          {'advance_event': 'Advanced'}
        ],
        [
          {'help': 'Help'}
        ]
    ],
    'has_car': True,
    'has_payment': False
};
>>> data
{'details': [[{'quick_event': 'Quick'}, {'advance_event': 'Advanced'}], [{'help': 'Help'}]], 'has_car': True, 'has_payment': False}
```

In a nutshell:

- Convert `=>` to `:`
- Convert `[]` to `{}` for maps.

Comment: this definitely fixes the immediate problem

Comment: The answer is great. My problem was fixed.

Answer (score 3):

In php use http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php to format the data as json.

In python convert the json to a dictionary.

Maybe check this link to see how to convert json to dictionary in python: 
[Converting JSON String to Dictionary Not List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19483351/converting-json-string-to-dictionary-not-list)

Comment: I have a PHP script and want to write that in Python. I can't do this!

Comment: check this out then: https://pythonspot.com/en/json-encoding-and-decoding-with-python/

Comment: this might help as well: https://developmentality.wordpress.com/2012/03/30/three-ways-of-creating-dictionaries-in-python/