# How to delete documents from multiple indices using particular field name in elasticsearch python?

Tags: python, curl, elasticsearch, logstash, pyelasticsearch

This is sample document.

```
{
"_index": "mqtt-index-2018.01.23",
"_type": "iot_data",
"_id": "AWEjA7LNRU4cTUO-Lyj4",
"_score": null,
"_source": {
"message": "{\"datastream_name\": \"roshni\", \"value\": 12, 
\"context\": {\"latitude\": 0, \"elevation\": 0, \"longitude\": 0}, 
\"device_id\": 31}",
"@version": "1",
"@timestamp": "2018-01-23T12:34:59.687Z",
"host": "iot-elk",
"topic": "telemetry/f2a55827ef554475a41c3c96369957f0/roshni",
"datastream_name": "roshni",
"value": 12,
"context": {
  "latitude": 0,
  "elevation": 0,
  "longitude": 0
},
"device_id": 31,
"tstamp": "2018-01-23T12:34:59.687Z"
},
"fields": {
"tstamp": [
  1516710899687
],
"@timestamp": [
  1516710899687
]
},
"sort": [
 1516710899687
]
}
```

I want to delete document using device_id field. 
How to delete it using API call or using python client? I have tried it using Document _id and particular index but i want to delete it by using device_id field or other field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting document from multiple indices in elasticsearch using following DELETE API call.

```
curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9200/mqtt-index-*/logs/_query' -d '{
"query" : {
    "match" : {"device_id": 31}
}
}' -i
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer without sample code:

- convert the json to a dict (see [Converting JSON String to Dictionary Not List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19483351/converting-json-string-to-dictionary-not-list))
- if you have many of those data structures, build a list of them if they match your search criteria (e.g. `if data["parsed_message"]["device_id"] not in list_of_forbidden_ids):`)

Answer (score 0):

In terms of using the raw API, I believe [this is what you are looking for](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html).

Depending on which python library you are using, it is actually easier in python. I use `elasticesearch-dsl-py`, where you build up query objects. [You can call delete on these query objects](http://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search_dsl.html?highlight=delete#delete-by-query).

In regards to spanning multiple indexes, ElasticSearch does support this, either using a wildcard `*`, or separating the indexes with commas.

Comment: client = Elasticsearch(hosts= '[172.16.2.121]')
 s = Search(using=client, index="mqtt-index-2018.01.24").query("match", value=10)
 response = s.delete()

 I have executed this code and got the error - 
 elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: TransportError(400, u'invalid_type_name_exception', u"Document mapping type name can't start with '_'")

Comment: response = s.delete()                                                                                               

    by running this, document is not getting deleted. In response its showing : 
                                                                                                               
        >>> print response   : 
        {u'_type': u'delete_by_query', u'created': True, u'_shards':...}

Answer (score 0):

You can also delete documents with matching multiple fields.

```
curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9200/mqtt-index-*/logs/_query' -d '{
"query" : {
    "bool": {
        "must":[
    {"match" : {"device_id":31}}, 
    {"match":  {"datastream_name": "test"}}
    ]
}
}' -i
```