# Adding keys of the same name into nested dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I'm dealing with a little issue. So I want to have a dictionary that looks like this json file

```
{"matches":[
    {"gameId":2585563902,"platformId":"NA1"},
    {"gameId":2412534524,"platformId":"NA1"},
    {"gameId":2412534524,"platformId":"NA1"}
]}
```

As you can see, the key elements have the same name, with different values.

The issue is that I am unable to do the same thing in python without adding a counter, which contains each of the keys and values. For example, I want to create 10 keys for matches, that contain gameId key and platformId key, and the code looks like that

```
myDict = {}
myDict["matches"] = {}
for a in range (10):
    myDict["matches"][a] = {}
    myDict["matches"][a]["gameId"] = a
    myDict["matches"][a]["platformId"] = a
```

which returns this

```
{'matches': {
0: {'gameId': 0, 'accountId': 0}, 
1: {'gameId': 1, 'accountId': 1}, 
2: {'gameId': 2, 'accountId': 2}
}}
```

While I understand the json file also uses the same form of a counter but is "invisible", I would like to know if it is possible to do the same in python3

Or is perhaps my reasoning wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting JSON String to Dictionary Not List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19483351/converting-json-string-to-dictionary-not-list). In particular [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48271216/499581) might provide what you are asking to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code snippet is making a dictionary of dictionaries while instead I assume you want it to make a list of dictionaries. You can do something like this instead.

```
myDict = {}
myDict["matches"] = []
for a in range (10):
    innerDict = {"gameId":a, "platformId":a}
    myDict["matches"].append(innerDict)
```

And in the end if you want this as an actual json you use the json standard library and use the dumps method to make a json object

```
obj = json.dumps(myDict)
```