# Accessing Array Values of Python variable which consist of JSON array

Tags: python, arrays, json

in this code variable "r" consist of JSON array. how to access only the attribute company using the python code. for example, the result must be "Apple, Inc."

```py
import pprint
import requests

MAC_URL = 'http://macvendors.co/api/%s'

r = requests.get(MAC_URL % 'BC:92:6B:A0:00:01')

pprint.pprint(r.json())
```

Result:

```
{'result': {'address': '1 Infinite Loop Cupertino CA US 95014 ',

        'company': 'Apple, Inc.',

        'mac_prefix': 'BC:92:6B'}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the json library to turn this into a dictionary, and then you can
acccess the company value by referencing the outer 'result' key and then the inner 'company' key.

```
from json import dump
response_dict = json.dump(r.json())
company = response_dict['result']['company']
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

Comment: @ADKD edited. thanks! If this helped you please accept the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is a list with dictionary inside . Take the dictionary part. Then you can access value for key: "company". To know how to take out dictionary from list, refer [Converting JSON String to Dictionary Not List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19483351/converting-json-string-to-dictionary-not-list)

You can also use https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
import json
MAC_URL = 'http://macvendors.co/api/%s'
r = requests.get(MAC_URL % 'BC:92:6B:A0:00:01')
response_dict = json.loads(json.dumps(r.json()))
company = response_dict['result']['company']
print(company)
```