# Parse JSON using Python

Tags: python, json

I am calling an API and I am getting a JSON response like the one above:

```
{
  "data": {
    "styles": [
      {
        "groups": [
          {
            "product": [
              {
                "code": "0000001",
                "date": null
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "product": [
              {
                "code": "0000002",
                "date": "2020-05-02T00:00:00.000Z"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "product": [
              {
                "code": "0000003",
                "date": "2020-04-22T00:00:00.000Z"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "groups": [
          {
            "product": [
              {
                "code": "0000011",
                "date": "2020-05-12T00:00:00.000Z"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "product": [
              {
                "code": "0000012",
                "date": "2020-05-12T00:00:00.000Z"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I am not familiar with handling JSON and this one is super nested. All I want to do is to create a tuple (or a dict) which would look like:

```
(0000001, null)
(0000002, 2020-05-02T00:00:00.000Z)
(0000003, 2020-04-22T00:00:00.000Z)
(0000011, 2020-05-12T00:00:00.000Z)
(0000012, 2020-05-12T00:00:00.000Z)
```

Could you please advice me one how to do that?

Comment: The answer here should work for you: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19483351/converting-json-string-to-dictionary-not-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import json

# your work

d = json.load(xxxx) # load it.
for i in d["data"]["styles"]:
    for j in i["groups"]:
        print((j['product'][0]['code'], j['product'][0]['date']))
```

Result:

```
('0000001', None) # In python, there is no null. it will be replace to None.
('0000002', '2020-05-02T00:00:00.000Z')
('0000003', '2020-04-22T00:00:00.000Z')
('0000011', '2020-05-12T00:00:00.000Z')
('0000012', '2020-05-12T00:00:00.000Z')
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `json` library:

```py
import json

def json_to_dict(api_response):
    # I assume the api response is a string 
    api_response_dict = json.loads(api_response)
    return api_response_dict
```

This will create one dictionary with all of the contents. Then you can parse this dictionary and take only the key-value pairs that you care about:

```py
list_of_products = []
for product_group in api_response_dict['data']['styles']:
    for product in product_group['groups']:
        code = product['product'][0]['code']
        date = product['product'][0]['date']
        list_of_products.append((code, date))
```

This was just an example.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is about parsing JSON with Python.

You can perform this using `json.loads` :

```
import json
my_string = '{"foo": "bar"}'
data = json.loads(my_string)
```

However, it looks like you are using an API response. If your using `requests` (and you should), you can use

```
response = requests.get([...])
data = response.json()
```