# python parse AWS http logs

Tags: amazon-web-services

i am now trying to parse AWS http logs in python.I got some logs as below.i would like to  convert it to dic.but it seems not standard json because some keys without "".i tried to use json5 but also failed.how can i made it?

```
{
  resource: '',
  path: '',
  httpMethod: 'POST',
  headers: {
    accept: '*/*',
  },
  multiValueHeaders: {
    accept: [ '*/*' ],
    'accept-encoding': [ 'gzip, deflate, br' ],
    'accept-language': [ 'zh-CN,zh-Hans;q=0.9' ]
  },
  queryStringParameters: {},
  multiValueQueryStringParameters: null,
  pathParameters: null,
  stageVariables: null,
  requestContext: {
    resourceId: '',
    resourcePath: '',
    identity: {
      cognitoIdentityPoolId: null,
      accountId: null,
      cognitoIdentityId: null,
      caller: null,
      sourceIp: '',
      principalOrgId: null,
      accessKey: null,
      cognitoAuthenticationType: null
    },
    domainName: '',
    apiId: ''
  },
  body: [Object: null prototype] { },
  isBase64Encoded: false
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to convert this json response to a dictionary in python?

Comment: yes,of course?do u know how to convert this json response to a dictionary in python?

Comment: Use json.loads() as recommended in this solution - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19483351/converting-json-string-to-dictionary-not-list

Comment: i know how to use json.loads(),but the response is not standered json.for example:keys without "" .so if i use json.loads(),i will get json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes.@KavishBaghel